# Configuration `locale` variable is deprecated - Android

Tags: android

I use this code to set the default language manually in multiple languages app:

```
public static void setLanguage(Context context, String languageCode){
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;  // Deprecated !!
    context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

so now we cant set locale by config.locale is deprecated because the variable is going to be removed in API 24.

So i saw that the alternative is to set:

config.setLocales();

locale

> Added in API level 1
>
> **Locale** locale
>
> This field was deprecated in API
>   level 24. Do not set or read this directly. Use getLocales() and
>   setLocales(LocaleList). If only the primary locale is needed,
>   getLocales().get(0) is now the preferred accessor.
>
> Current user preference for the locale, corresponding to locale
>   resource qualifier.

I noticed also that there is `setLocale(Locale)` as well but for api 17 and above

I checked the setLocales(LocalList) documentation and it is marked in grey as if it is also deprecated !

so what can be solution for this !?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Hope this helps, I also added the getters.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config){
    return config.locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config){
    return config.getLocales().get(0);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale){
    config.locale = locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale){
    config.setLocale(locale);
}

public static void setLanguage(Context context, String languageCode){
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        setSystemLocale(config, locale);
    }else{
        setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

### UPDATE 12/3/2016

Since context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration() is now deprecated, I highly recommend that you check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704077/2199894) and adopt a different approach to overwriting Android system configuration.

**Better Solution:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704077/2199894

Comment: for setSystemLocale(. version N .)  google recommends to user  setLocales instead of setLocale. you can easily add a list the locales even if you have only one:  config.setLocales(new LocaleList( locale));   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#setLocale(android.os.Locale)

Comment: Deprecation is only for direct access to config.locale in order to force developers to use setters and getters. 
Also, setLocale is introduced in the last N release so it is safe to use it in case one doesn't have more than one locale.

Comment: Hey, I really liked ur answer, but you posted a link with a better solution, could you please briefly explain why is it better? if I'm not mistaken, the "better solution" suggests to run that piece of code in every activity, which I would prefer to avoid if possible, even though I have a BaseActivity... Thanks in advance !

Comment: For Samsung devices with 6.0.1, there is a issue. Locale is working for only 1st time.. from second time it is taking device default.. Any solution for this?