# How to change android app locale/language runtime/programmatically

Tags: android, localization

How to change android app locale/language runtime/programmatically, best practice way?

I've looked other solutions on so but they got depreciated accepted solutions. Hope to this will be future reference.

Comment: You can write a custom context wrapper and attach it as base context in your activity. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated/40704077#40704077) is a reference point.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. [Here is the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android/43938564#43938564)

Answer (score -2):

For Android `< N`

```
Locale locale = new Locale(mLanguageCode);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration();
config.locale = locale;
mContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(
    config,
    mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
);
activity.recreate();
```

For `>= N`

```
Locale locale = new Locale(mLanguageCode);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration();
config.setLocale(locale);
mContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(
    config,
    mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
);
activity.recreate();
```

Comment: Sorry but updateConfiguration method was deprecated in API level 25. See createConfigurationContext(Configuration).
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

Comment: You're right, I don't try yet to use this new function `createConfigurationContext()`