# Language change to arabic not working?

Tags: android

I have implemented change language from settings as per this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated/40704077#40704077) , but after killing of my application some of the screen of application turned to english.

I have implemented code as below
Code for Splash Screen

```
String   deviceLanguage = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();

if (!"en".equalsIgnoreCase(deviceLanguage) && !"ar".equalsIgnoreCase(deviceLanguage)){
            deviceLanguage="en";
        }
((AppController)getApplication()).appLang= Utilities.getSaveData(this, getString(R.string.key_language),deviceLanguage);
```

Code for Detail Activity

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, ((AppController)newBase.getApplicationContext()).appLang));
}
```

Note : I got this problem in one plus 3T device and genymotion emulator with 5.1 android version

Comment: The actual problem is customize os in some customize os in that they can select multiple languages same time and it creates issue

Answer (score 1):

```
final Resources res = appContext.getResources();
final Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("ar", "AE");      
res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);
```

After updating configuration, Restart the activity as mentioned below

```
finish();
final Intent intent = getIntent();
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: Something like this, but I would rather put the locale setting into `Application` already, and restart whole app after change, not only current Activity. I can't recall any details (since I last did something similar, and that's like 3-4 years back), but IIRC on some older versions of Android and on some devices, restarting only Activity may produce some unwanted artefacts, with some bits staying initialized with the original Locale.