# Deprecated updateConfiguration() - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I defined `layouts` for multiple languages and multiple devices like below:

[image]

I set proper `layout` with custom language like bellow :

```
String languageToLoad = "ar"; 
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setLocale(locale);
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

For language (ar - Arabic) I fetch `layout-ldrtl` or `layout-ldrtl-sw600dp` and other language (en - English) I fetch `layout-ldltr` or `layout-ldltr-sw600dp` and above code good work.

**Problem :** In this line `getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);` say me `updateConfiguration` is deprecated and then I use from `createConfigurationContext` but when I use from this method the source don't work true and don't get me proper layout .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem. I use from this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704077/4813855) then in my `activity` use from bellow code :

```
Context context = MyContextWrapper.wrap(this, "en");
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(context.getResources().getLayout(R.layout.activity_main), null);
this.setContentView(view);
```