# Android Locale Changed but translated strings not coming in the app

Tags: android, localization

Following is the Application code of my Android app:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    private Locale locale = null;

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (locale != null)
        {
            newConfig.locale = locale;
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();

        String lang = settings.getString(getString(R.string.pref_language), "");
        if (! "".equals(lang) && ! config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang))
        {
            locale = new Locale(lang);
            Log.i("Locale" , lang);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }
}
```

I have got to change the value of `settings.getString(getString(R.string.pref_language), "");` from the Settings Activity of my app.

The problem is none of the strings (which have a translation) and are accessed using `getString()` method, are showing the translated text.

EDIT1 : I am using Android 8.0

Comment: are you using android 8 ?
there is some changes on android 8 for locales

Comment: Yes Android 8.0

Comment: Took some cue from this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated/40704077#40704077 and it is now working

Answer (score 1):

In android 8, the behavior of the Locales changed, now every Activity context will take its locale, i.e if you in Activity1 and changed the locale for Activity1, then Activity2 will remain on the default locale.

The solution is to change the locale for every Activity and your issue will be fixed.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. How the Locale of each activity is supposed to be changed? Should I do it in onCreate before setContentView() method

Comment: Still not working. Locale of the system has changed but the string file values of that locale aren't fetched. I can see the date inside the app changed to that locale language.

Comment: u got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `getString(R.string.pref_language)` the call will return the string from the language matching `Locale.getDefault()` as long as a translation is provided.

If a translation is not provided it will return the default language, that is the language your using in the `values/strings.xml` file.

All translated values are in `values-xx` folders, where xx is the 2 letter ISO code for the language.

Comment: `Log.i("Locale" , lang);` returns the 2 digit code of the language I set (hi), and I have also provided the translations for the strings referenced with `getString()` , but I am still not getting the translated values

Comment: Strange... I remember when I first had a similar problem. I am from Norway and here we have 2 written languages, nynorsk and bokmal.

At first I tried to provide a translation for no, but what I needed to provide was translations for nb (bokmal) and nn (nynorsk).

Could you be facing something similar?