# How can I prevent the device font size effect of a Xamarin Android app?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

If I change the device font then it will also change my app font. I do not want to change my app font according the device font.

So I searched about this, and I found *[Dimension](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)*.

Please let me know how to use dp in Xamarin for Android. Also suggest me any other proper way to resolve this.

Comment: "any other proper way to resolve this" -- allow your fonts to change size based on the system font size. The user is saying "I would like larger fonts" (or possibly "I would like smaller fonts"). You, by trying to prevent this, are telling the user that you do not care what the user wants. The user, in turn, may not appreciate your app very much.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I just want for some entry to prevent font size. So I am looking for this.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated) is about the `UpdateConfiguration` was deprecated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your activity, add this:

```
public override Resources Resources {
    get
    {
        Resources res = base.Resources;
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.SetToDefaults();
        res.UpdateConfiguration(config, res.DisplayMetrics);
        return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: Phenomenal, many thanks. Insights into iOS equivalent? Possibly in `AppDelegate`?

Comment: @jtth - Haven't been an issue in any iOS devices in my experience. Do you think there will be font size variations in iOS?

Comment: @jtth you may have found it already, but the iOS equivalent is a platform specific property set on the Application called `EnableAccessibilityScalingForNamedFontSizes` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/named-font-size-scaling

Answer (score 12):

Robbit's answer is right, but Resources.UpdateConfiguration() has been deprecated.
So, currently, it should be done like this:

```
public override Resources Resources 
{
    get
    {
        var config = new Configuration();
        config.SetToDefaults();

        return CreateConfigurationContext(config).Resources;
    }
}
```

Comment: this makes app crashing on orientation changes via null reference !

Answer (score 8):

I used [Rafael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649874/how-to-prevent-device-font-size-effect-of-xamarin-android-app/57501807#57501807), but I was getting this error when I tried to set `Application.Current.MainPage`:

> Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>

I solved it doing this:

```
public override Android.Content.Res.Resources Resources
{
    get
    {
        var config = base.Resources.Configuration;
        if (config == null)
            config = new Configuration();
        config.FontScale = 1f;
        return CreateConfigurationContext(config).Resources;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! It's better to check the config instance.

Answer (score 3):

In the Xamarin.Forms Android MainActivity.cs, override the Resources and set the configuration to default to restrict the font size effect on application.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
public override Resources Resources
        {
            get
            {
                Resources resource = base.Resources;
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.SetToDefaults();
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.NMr1)
                {
                    return CreateConfigurationContext(configuration).Resources;
                }
                else
                {
                    resource.UpdateConfiguration(configuration, resource.DisplayMetrics);
                    return resource;
                }
            }
        }
}
```