# Android system font size effects app font size in maui app

Tags: c#, android, maui

How to disable system font size scaling for maui app?
android 33 version.

I tried to set configuration to default within MainActivity:

```
public override Android.Content.Res.Resources Resources
{
    get
    {
        Android.Content.Res.Configuration configuration = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration();
        configuration.SetToDefaults();

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.NMr1)
        {
            return CreateConfigurationContext(configuration).Resources;
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            base.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
            return base.Resources;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.Resources;
        }
    }
}
```

in debug it resets display metrics density to default, but once in a while i see scaled font as system one.
Also try tried to set:

```
configuration.FontScale = (float)1;
```

but the same.

Comment: Try adapting one of the Xamarin answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649874/how-can-i-prevent-the-device-font-size-effect-of-a-xamarin-android-app, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363019/preventing-android-12-system-font-size-from-affecting-in-app-font-size-crash, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289763/disable-system-font-size-effect-in-my-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code below in the MainActivity.cs file. It can prevent to change the application font to match the system font.

```
 protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context @base)
     {
         Configuration configuration = new(@base.Resources.Configuration)
         {
             FontScale = 1.0f
         };
         ApplyOverrideConfiguration(configuration);
         base.AttachBaseContext(@base);
     }
```

Comment: thanks, it did the trick, but still need to set each ui element custom font size(dont use default or system fontSizes)

Comment: This does not work with named font sizes, such as Medium. Is there a way to make it work with those as well?

Comment: How would we do something similar for iOS

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use property

**FontAutoScalingEnabled="False"**

where in the label you want to.