# How can I restrict the device font size effect only on certain pages of a Xamarin Android app?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, fonts

If I change my device's font then my app's font will also change. I don't want to change the app's font based on the device's font on certain pages. The application's use case lies in the med field and that requires at least some pages of it to be adaptive for people with vision health conditions.

The use cases of some of the pages/views of my application may require adaptive font change, so the goal is to prevent the system dependent font scalability only on the certain views where the textures overlap the text if the font is *Large*.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649874/how-can-i-prevent-the-device-font-size-effect-of-a-xamarin-android-app)  solution but it seems to be too strict and blocking the use cases of other views.

Could you please suggest me any other suitable ways to solve this problem.

I have tried using this example from the answers in the question I referred to.

```
public override Android.Content.Res.Resources Resources
{
    get
    {
        var config = base.Resources.Configuration;
        if (config == null)
            config = new Configuration();
        config.FontScale = 1f;
        return CreateConfigurationContext(config).Resources;
    }
}
```

However, seems that having access through the resources I am blocking adaptive font on a complete level, what is not an expected solution for my case. I am looking for a more specific solution that will affect onlz specific views of the app.

Comment: You can't do this in the xamarin.forms. There is only one MainActivity in the xamarin.forms project. You can only change all the views or none view.

Comment: That's also what I was able to find. Thought maybe there is any work-around found. Thanks anyways!