# Android context.getResources.updateConfiguration() deprecated how to resolve?

Tags: java, android, locale, deprecated

Just recently, `context.getResources().updateConfiguration()` has been deprecated in Android API 25 and I need to change language of my app which user selects. I am using this method to change language

```
  private void setLanguage(String language){
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    con.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    prefData.setCurrentLanguage(language);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
```

But getting Deprecated api warning, I have just started android development. So any suggestion will be helpful on how to resolve this warning.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated)

Answer (score 4):

I found below code in the `Resource` source code.

```
 /**
     * Store the newly updated configuration.
     *
     * @deprecated See {@link android.content.Context#createConfigurationContext(Configuration)}.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public void updateConfiguration(Configuration config, DisplayMetrics metrics) {
        updateConfiguration(config, metrics, null);
    }
```

The doc says it has been deprecated that you should use `Context.createConfigurationContext(Configuration)` instead.