# Locale Changed, but String Resources are not updating

Tags: android, configuration, localization, locale, getresource

I have a problem in changing locale, I have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704077/2199589
and the following snippet with both BaseContext and ApplicationContext, none of them works well. I have saved the current language in share preference. Even that value is correct, string resources are not updating as the way they should be.

```
public void changeLanguage(String languageToLoad) {
    showLog("Language to be loaded :-  "+ languageToLoad);
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration(getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
    config.setLocale(locale);
    getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics() );

}
```

I have updated the UI after calling this method, and the UI actually did the refresh. So any idea what went wrong? Please help me with this.

Comment: Locale changing on Android just sound easy. But actually it is complex thing depending on API version. Try reading this article https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40221711/5110595)

Comment: I have tried that link @HemantParmar ,didnt go well for me