# Android Resources.UpdateConfiguration(Configuration, DisplayMetrics) deprecated

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

**EDIT 2**

[image: sample]

**EDIT**

**Override attachBaseContext method to update the context in activity**

```
protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context @base)
{
    base.AttachBaseContext(@base);
}
```

**end edit**

In Android API 25 `Resources.UpdateConfiguration(Configuration, DisplayMetrics)` was deprecated and it's advised to use `Context context = CreateConfigurationContext(Configuration);` instead.

**Current implementation**

```
public override Resources Resources
{
    get
    {
        Resources res = base.Resources;
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.SetToDefaults();

        res.UpdateConfiguration(config, res.DisplayMetrics);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Referencing [Android context.getResources.updateConfiguration() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated?noredirect=1&lq=1) as a guide, tried the following:

```
public override Resources Resources
{
    get
    {
        Configuration overrideConfiguration = base.Resources.Configuration;
        overrideConfiguration.SetToDefaults();
        Context context = CreateConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration);
        Resources res = context.Resources;
        return res;
    }
}
```

However this produces anomalous errors..

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Error inflating class
com.android.internal.widget.DialogTitle
```

How to correctly implement `Context context = CreateConfigurationContext(Configuration)`?

Note 'Current implementation' works perfectly fine but as encouraged to not use deprecated code want to the replacement working

Comment: have you override attachBaseContext method to update the context  in activity ?

Comment: `base.AttachBaseContext(@base);` here should use your new context not @base

Comment: try to add `Configuration overrideConfiguration = @base.Resources.Configuration;
            overrideConfiguration.SetToDefaults();
            Context context = CreateConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration);
            base.AttachBaseContext(context);` to attachBaseContext  method,then in your Resources override call  `Resources res = context.Resources;return res;`

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Visual added. `@base` returns null?`context.Resources` how are we passing context here, should this be `base.Resources`?

Comment: yes,base.Resources,not sure of success, but give it a try

Comment: could you share your project ?That way maybe could find the mistakes more accurately!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's your need，you could change the **attachBaseContext** method like this,it could work:

```
protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context @base)
    {
        Configuration overrideConfiguration = new Configuration();
        overrideConfiguration = @base.Resources.Configuration;
        overrideConfiguration.SetToDefaults();
        Context context = @base.CreateConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration);
        base.AttachBaseContext(context);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This really helped :)