# Resources.UpdateConfiguration is obsolete

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to prevent system font-size changing, effects to my xamarin forms android application. I tried with below code in MainActivity.cs and its working, but it tells me that it is deprecated **(res.UpdateConfiguration)**. I tried some other codes, but no luck.

```
public override Resources Resources
{
    get
    {
        Resources res = base.Resources;
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.SetToDefaults();
        res.UpdateConfiguration(config, res.DisplayMetrics);
        return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`context.getResources().updateConfiguration()` has been deprecated in Android API 25 and it is advised to use context.createConfigurationContext() instead.

```
public override Resources Resources
{
  get
  {              
   Configuration config = new Configuration();
   config.SetToDefaults();
               
   Context context = CreateConfigurationContext(config);
   Resources resources = context.Resources;

   return resources;
  }
}
```

Check [Android context.getResources.updateConfiguration() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated)

## Update

If you want to change the font size, you should override the method `AttachBaseContext`.

### Java

```
protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context @base)
{
  // base.AttachBaseContext(@base);
  Configuration config = new Configuration();
  config.SetToDefaults();
  config.FontScale = 1.0f;
  Context context = @base.CreateConfigurationContext(config);
  base.AttachBaseContext(context);
}
```

### Kotlin

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    
    val config =  Configuration();
    config.setToDefaults();
    config.setLocale(Locale("mr"))
    
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase.createConfigurationContext(config));
}
```

Comment: i put this code inside the MainActivity.cs but no change to the interface after changing the system font size

Comment: still not working. I am testing on my xiaomi mi4c android 7 phone. I think **DisplayMetrics** is do the different. in deprecated one it has the **DisplayMetrics**

Comment: its working. i did a mistake. I have checked in a API 24 phone both times. That was the problem. thank you

Comment: I get `Configuration is a namespace but is used like a type` error.

Comment: For java most of the Methods are with small letters in case you wonder the errors after copy pasting:
- attachBaseContext
- setToDefaults
- config.fontScale
- base.createConfigurationContext

Comment: Where do we put this code?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like using protected override, you can use

```
private void initFontScale()
{
     Configuration configuration = Resources.Configuration;
     configuration.FontScale = (float)1.45;
     //0.85 small, 1 standard, 1.15 big，1.3 more bigger ，1.45 supper big 
     DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
     metrics.ScaledDensity = configuration.FontScale * metrics.Density;
     BaseContext.ApplicationContext.CreateConfigurationContext(configuration); BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.SetTo(metrics);
}

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    initFontScale();
    ...
}
```