# Change Language while using Navigation Component API 24+

Tags: android, android-fragments, localization, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

TL;DR We want to change the locale (API 24+) for a to be displayed fragments while all these fragments are going to be inside the same activity.

We are using `NavHostFragment`, and `start_up_nav_graph.xml`.
This graph has multiple fragments i.e. Log-in, Onboarding, GDPR ..etc

In this flow, If after logging in we find that you are a German user, we try to change your locale to German.
In the current scenario, all the up-coming fragments (such as onboarding and GDPR) are going to be displayed in the device's locale, not German.

We can't use `attachBaseContext` in the activity like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704077/1390881), because the activity has already been created.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing same pain brother. i tried to do

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mToolbar,mNavController, mAppBarConfiguration);
```

but this is also not helping because Toolbar Title and Navigation Drawer items are using old resources and when i'm doing `activity.recreate()` then it's actually happening but when you close app and restart it again same problem...

Comment: What I did was split it into two parts, the 1st part of the start-up flow in which I don't know the language of the user and the 2nd part which I know the language of the user. Once I have this information, I start the 2nd part and then I can `attachBaseContext` as I would usually do. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with .

**Note**:- This is just a hack and not a correct solution

Once a language is changed, save the language in sharepreferences , override all the required methods in the activity you have , use the language from share preferences . Send an event to Activity and in activity , once getting event in activity you can do 1 of the below 2 things

Option1 :-

`recreate()` . This works well but there is a issue with fragment backstack .

Option 2 :-

```
finish()
intent.putExtra("LANGUAGE_CHANGE", true)
startActivity(intent)   // or getIntent() if using java
overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
```

And in oncreate if you get `LANGUAGE_CHANGE` in intent then go to the required fragment .