# When changing Locale, getResources from Application not updated. Only Activity getResources is updated correctly

Tags: android, android-resources, android-context

The application has **Multi-Lingual** support. But we have an issue with `Resources` refresh with the application context.

Currently, my `ViewModels` are extending `AndroidViewModel` so that we can have access to Application instance inside our `ViewModels`.  But the problem is that the **Application resources** are not refreshed immediately after Locale change.

So, if I change my Locale and come back to my LoginActivity the following code gives different outputs

```
    String testText = getString(R.string.enter_email);
    Timber.e("-- From Activity --");
    Timber.e(testText);

    Timber.e("-- From Application--");
    testText = getApplication().getString(R.string.enter_email);
    Timber.e(testText);
```

the **Logcat output** of this snippet is as follows

```
E/LoginActivity: -- From Activity --
E/LoginActivity: الرجاء إدخال البريد الإلكتروني
E/LoginActivity: -- From Application--
E/LoginActivity: Please enter your email
```

I am doing my Locale update with the following snippet:

```
public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    saveLocale(context, language);
    CountryUtils.getDefaultCountryISO(context));
    Locale locale = new Locale(language, CountryUtils.getDefaultCountryISO(context));
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return context;
}
```

I have followed all the steps as mentioned in this [blog](https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated).

What I need to understand is why do we have different resources out between `getApplication().getString()` and `this.getString()`?

Answer (score 0):

Add below method in your activity

```
 override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(PbContext.wrap(newBase, getmAppLanguage()))
}
```

Please find below the extend custom context :

```
public class PbContext extends ContextWrapper {

public PbContext(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static PbContext wrap(Context context, String language) {
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();

    if (language != null) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            setSystemLocale(config, locale);
        } else {
            setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
        }

        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);

    }
    //Updating application
    SampleApplication.setAppConfig(context);
    return new PbContext(context);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config){
    return config.locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config){
    return config.getLocales().get(0);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale){
    config.locale = locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale){
    config.setLocale(locale);
}}
```