# MaterialDatePicker RTL month pagination buttons

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design, android-datepicker

anyone knows how to make the android MaterialDatePicker support RTL including the arrows for month pagination?

you can see that the should be facing the opposite way..
any suggestions how to mirror the arrow buttons?
[image]

EDIT:

my custom theme which I declared the View to be RTL:

```
    <style name="datePickerTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderTitle">@style/materialCalendarTitle</item>
        <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
    </style>
```

the locale that I am using in my app (hebrew Israel):

```
        val languageToLoad = "iw_IL"
        val locale = Locale(languageToLoad)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        baseContext.resources.configuration.setLocale(locale)
```

my `MaterialDatePicker` initialization :

```
            val datePickerBuilder =
                MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
            val constraints = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
                .setValidator(object : CalendarConstraints.DateValidator {
                    override fun describeContents(): Int {
                        return 0
                    }

                    override fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel?, p1: Int) {

                    }

                    override fun isValid(date: Long): Boolean {
                        //checks if date is more than 3 months
                        if (Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis - date > 90 * daysInMilli
                            || Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis < date
                        ) {
                            return false
                        }
                        return true
                    }
                })
            datePickerBuilder
                .setTitleText("החל מתאריך")
                .setTheme(R.style.datePickerTheme)
                .setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds() - 3 * daysInMilli)
                .setCalendarConstraints(constraints.build())
            val datePicker = datePickerBuilder.build()
```

`R.style.datePickerTheme`:

```
    <style name="materialCalendarTitle">
        <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="datePickerTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderTitle">@style/materialCalendarTitle</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge, this bug has been fixed with this [commit](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/ea763862b4e7c9bc3c484f9b3b19f851c353a9a9) which is available updating material library  to version `1.3.0-alpha03` and above. I would try updating to at least `1.3.0` if you can.

**UPDATE**:
I've run the material sample app `catalog` here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android

Then I've added this method to programmatically change locale in the `MainActivity`:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public static void setLocale(Activity activity, String languageCode) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Resources resources = activity.getResources();
    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

And used it like this in the `onCreate`:

```
//wrapped in build check just to hide warnings
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    setLocale(this, "iw_IL");
}
```

This was the result when navigating to **DatePicker** sample page and pressing "launch material date picker".

[image]

As you see month arrows are fine so the problem is in your implementation. You should check the sample app to find it or start removing your customizations step by step until it works.

Comment: I just updated to `1.4.0-beta01` but it still looks the same.. 
what am I missing? how would you make your materialDatePIcker RTL anyway? maybe I am doing it wrong

Comment: MaterialDatePicker should use RTL by default based on current locale, without expliciting it in the style.
Can you update your answer adding the MaterialDatePicker initialization code and the locale you are using to test it?

Comment: I added those details above, is there anything related there? thanks

Comment: I tried replacing my function of Locale changing to yours and the arrows work well, but 
`resources.updateConfiguration()` is deprecated... any replacement?

Comment: There are a lot of alternatives (but not easy ones), check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated

Comment: @YarinShitrit don't forget to flag an answer as accepted if it helped you.