# How do I change the applications language?

Tags: android, kotlin, settings

I am trying enable language changing through a drop-down menu in my SettingsFragment. I already have three different strings.xml files in their respective folders (res/values for English, res/values-fr for Franch, etc.) done and translated.
Some might add that "Why not just default to the phone language?", but the client requested language changing in the settings.

When running this and clicking the button, the app properly restarts, but the language stays in English.

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var applyButton: Button
    private lateinit var languageSpinner: Spinner
    private val languages = listOf("English", "French", "Dutch")

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)
        languageSpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.language_spinner)
        applyButton = view.findViewById(R.id.apply_button)
        populateLanguageSpinner()
        loadSelectedLanguage()

        applyButton.setOnClickListener {
            applySettings()
        }
        return view
    }

    private fun populateLanguageSpinner() {
        // Inputs the values of the languages array into the spinner (dropdown menu)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages)
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        languageSpinner.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun saveSelectedLanguage(language: String) {
        // Saves the selected language in SharedPreferences
        val preferences = activity?.getSharedPreferences("MyAppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = preferences?.edit()
        editor?.putString("language", language)
        editor?.apply()
    }

    private fun loadSelectedLanguage() {
        // Loads the selected language from SharedPreferences and updates locale if needed.
        val preferences = activity?.getSharedPreferences("MyAppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val selectedLanguage = preferences?.getString("language", null)

        if (selectedLanguage == null) {
            // Default to English if the language is not set from some reason
            saveSelectedLanguage("English")
            updateLocale("English") //does it ned to be here?
        } else {
            // Language is set, proceed as before
            updateLocale(selectedLanguage)

            // Set selected language in the spinner
            val languageIndex = languages.indexOf(selectedLanguage)
            if (languageIndex != -1) {
                languageSpinner.setSelection(languageIndex)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateLocale(language: String): Context {
        // Updates the locale based on the selected language.
        // The locale is used to change the display language of the app.
        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)

        val activity = requireActivity()
        val configuration = Configuration(activity.resources.configuration)
        configuration.setLocale(locale)

        val context = activity.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
        val resources = context.resources
        val config = resources.configuration
        config.setLocale(locale)
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics) //deprecated??

        return context
    }



    private fun applySettings() {
        val selectedLanguage = languages[languageSpinner.selectedItemPosition]
        saveSelectedLanguage(selectedLanguage)
        // Update locale and get the new context
        val newContext = updateLocale(selectedLanguage)

        // Update UI elements using the new context
        updateUI(newContext)

        // Show a notification about app restart
        Toast.makeText(newContext, getString(R.string.app_restarting), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        // Restart the app
        val intent = Intent(newContext, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun updateUI(context: Context) { //TODO: update function
        val textView = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.my_text_view)
        textView?.text = context.getString(R.string.my_string)
    }
}
```

Tried removing and playing with different things, and ended up either crashing the program, or plainly not changing the languages.
A couple of sub-questions:

1. Are the comments inside my functions correct? I am still learning the language and hope I got the basics of it well.
2. Specifically in the line        `resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)` 
   It keeps telling me that it's deprecated. Is there another way or solution? Or should I just ignore that?

P.S. I see that many answers posted on here are more about Java then Kotlin, and the solutions seemed to not work well on me.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704077/4818247