# Android: Change language in app programatically without deprecated methods

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

I am looking for the best solution to change language in app without restart application for Android 7. A lot of solutions contains a deprecated methods for ex.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which method there is deprecated? Did you read the documentation for it to see what it suggests?

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/39595646/5727285

Comment: updateConfiguration(..), in documentation recommended a Locate builder but for me it's not work maybe i do this in wrong way. Maybe somebody can put here an example how to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuration \`locale\` variable is deprecated - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589841/configuration-locale-variable-is-deprecated-android)

Comment: @AmeerHamza still there an updateConfiguration(..) is deprecated

Comment: the dupe link will handle the deprecated call with annotation so follow the duplicate link implementation

Comment: @PavneetSingh so you recommend to use a deprecated code? because i don't understand your answer

Comment: try this one for updateConfiguration http://stackoverflow.com/a/40291570/5727285

Comment: when a function is deprecated then solution is either you get a replacement or you can use the deprecated one in old platform and new one  for newer platforms , the appropriate version of that function will be called according to the annotation check

Comment: Ok i know how annotation works but updateConfiguration is use for evry platfrom in examples and this function is deprecated

Comment: @PavneetSingh Well... We all know we need to get a replacement or using annotation to handle older and newer platform differently. What we ask is, in the new platform, what should we use to handle this task?

Comment: @Kurotsuki for API 25 and above use [createConfigurationContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createConfigurationContext(android.content.res.Configuration))

Comment: use createConfigurationContext:https://github.com/hosamazzam/AndroidChangeLanguage/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/freeapps/hosamazzam/androidchangelanguage

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
 Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    locale = new Locale("en_US);
    conf.setLocale(locale);
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```